# Аутентификация и создание платежа - PHP

Tags: php, html, curl, аутентификация, платежи

Доброго времени суток, дали тестовое задание, необходимо сделать аутентификацию и далее сделать страницу создания платежа, который будет возвращать `checkout link “redirect_url”`, после этого протестировать все это на *Behat* и *Mink*. Дали ссылку на пример https://getpayever.com/developer/api-documentation/ (первые две секции). Прошу помочь мне и поделиться опытом в таких вопросах: что бы я не делал, все равно не работает библиотека curl, я уже и файл *ini* изменял, и *Path* указывал для php и curl, ничего не помогло, а без нее, как я понял, данное задание будет сделать новичку очень сложно. И второе, я искал толковую информацию про behat и mink для не профессионала, но нашел несколько конференций и документацию. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы подразумеваете под "не работает библиотека curl"? Приведите пожалуйста пример кода, как вы ее используете, а также текст ошибки.

Comment: $curl = curl_init();
$params = array(
  'client_id' => '12345_client_id_string',
  'client_secret' => 'client_secret_string',
  'grant_type' => 'http://www.payever.de/api/payment',
  'scope' => 'API_CREATE_PAYMENT',
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://mein.payever.de/oauth/v2/token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
   echo $response;}

Comment: Ошибка: Call to undefined function curl_int()

Answer (score 0):

У вас не установлен, либо не подключен модуль curl. Вам нужно установить его.

Если у вас Windows, то нужно раскомментировать строчку в php.ini:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

Также проверьте, что в папке с модулями присутствует нужная dll.

Если у вас Ubuntu/Debian, то можете установить необходимое расширение с помощью apt-get (пример для версии 5.6, замените на свою):

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```

Для centos используйте yum:

```
yum install php-curl
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня Windows, я сделал все, смог найти по этой теме, строку в php.ini раскомментировал, php_curl.dll присутствует, в Path пути для папки php прописаны, но ошибка та же.

Comment: после правки php.ini сервер перезапускали?

Comment: да, даже компьютер перезагружал, результат один

Comment: Вы используете какой-то готовый веб сервер типа Openserver и тп? Или самостоятельно настраивали php?

Comment: Я использую Apache, также просматривал с помощью сервера в phpstorm,также в mamp, php скачал архив седьмой версии и подключил к apache.